# Java Connecting URL and downloading a zip but when extracting the zip it's not properly downloaded

Tags: java, zip, inputstream, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I am sending a request XML to the URL and receiving a zip file to the given path. 
Sometimes I'm facing troubles when the bandwidth is low this zip file, most likely 120MB size is not getting downloaded properly. And getting an error when extracting the zip file. Extracting happens from the code as well. When I download in high bandwidth this file gets download without issue.

I'm looking for a solution without making the bandwidth high, from program level are there any ways to download this zip file, may be part by part or something like that? Or anyother solution that you all are having is highly appreciated.

Downloading :

```
        url = new URL(_URL);
        sc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        sc.setDoInput(true);
        sc.setDoOutput(true);
        sc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        sc.connect();

        OutputStream mOstr = sc.getOutputStream();
        mOstr.write(request.getBytes());

        InputStream in = sc.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);

        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[86384];
        while ((count = in.read(buffer,0,buffer.length)) > 0)
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);

        out.close();
```

Extracting :

```
try {

        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path+zFile);

        Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();

        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {

            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();

            String name = path+"/data_FILES/"+zipEntry.getName();
            long size = zipEntry.getSize();
            long compressedSize = zipEntry.getCompressedSize();
            System.out.printf("name: %-20s | size: %6d | compressed size: %6d\n", name, size, compressedSize);

            File file = new File(name);

            if (name.endsWith("/")) {
                file.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            File parent = file.getParentFile();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }

            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[86384];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                fos.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();

        }
        zipFile.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log("Error in extracting zip file ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is this an academic task? Why are you using so many low-level stuff, have you tried Apache Virtual File System (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/)?

Comment: Which error do you get when extracting? EOF?

Comment: This is what I'm getting when extracting.

Archive:  /var/log/rezg/app/07-05-2013/data
[/var/log/rezg/app/07-05-2013/data]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /var/log/rezg/app/07-05-2013/data or
          /var/log/rezg/app/07-05-2013/data.zip, and cannot find /var/log/rezg/app/07-05-2013/data.ZIP, period.

Comment: Is there any error log in downloading?

Comment: No I'm not getting any error for downloading, it just stops in the middle. After downloading, the program moves to extract the zip file then only the error occurs.

Comment: Can you tell me which object is this? 

`mOstr.write(request.getBytes());`

I can't run the download part because of this request.